# Using Mu editor on RPi for Python version 3.7. Copying script written (and worked) on 2.7 and getting syntax error on script

Tags: pi-4, python-3

Getting syntax error and "cannot understand this line, check for missing characters" statement for this line:  GPIO.setup(LED1, GPIO.OUT)  plus a continuation line under-indented for visual indent error comment.  The line indicated was not indented.

Are these indicated errors a function of the two different versions of Python 2.7v3.7? What do they mean, particularly if the script worked just fine on a 2.7 version?

Comment: For future reference you should post the text of the script and the text of the error message.  The script and error will contain more useful information than your summary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Python 2.7, however there were few significant differences between them, so working script in 2.7 may not work in 3. Python is indentation sensitive, so if the line is indented just for visual, but it does not need to be indented, the interpreter will consider it as a an error. Check also for some single spaces etc. In Python you indent only lines which supposed to be indented, like in loops, conditional statements, etc.

Take a look here: [Python Indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp#)